# Check if a Perl module is installed from within a Python program

Tags: python, perl

I have a Python program that runs an `os.system` command which is dependent on a Perl module in order to generate some graphics.

What is the best way to check if potential users of my program have this module installed?

Comment: There is a bigger picture here. Perl won't search the `PATH` for its modules - it has its own list of directories in `@INC`. And you shouldn't be anticipating what may go wrong with a Perl program - that is Perl's job. You will always miss a beat if you try to field all possible errors before you call the script

Answer (score 4):

If the command calls the default Perl with no additional library paths, you can just try to run

```
perl -MModule -e1
```

and check its exit status.

Comment: Also don't forget to redirect STDERR away to /dev/null or something, otherwise this will print an error message if the module isn't found.